# can't match a string with pattern in Python

Tags: python, python-re

I'm been programming Java for a long time and recently I've started Python but there's something I can't figure out

```
import re

test_string = "1989 1989"
matched = re.match("\\d+", test_string)
print(bool(matched))
```

I'm expecting it to return false, however it returns true. basically I'm just looking for the counterpart of String.matches() in java... I thought maybe you could help me out! thank you in advance

Comment: Turn your regex string into raw string by putting a `r` before it. `r"\\d+"` and it will work as you expected.

Comment: @Asocia No, `'\\d+'` is entirely correct; using raw strings, which is a good recommendation, would mean using `r'\d+'`, not `r'\\d+'`. But that won’t solve OP’s problem.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The OP says *I'm expecting it to return false, however it returns true.* So I thought they are expecting false because the test string doesn't contain "\" symbol but the regex searches for "\" symbol. Currently the regex just searches for a number, and putting `r` before string will make it search for "\" symbol also, hence will return false.

Comment: And I don't know java so I have no idea what `String.matches()` does if the actual question is that.

Answer (score 1):

`re.match` matches if any prefix of the string matches the pattern. You probably want `re.fullmatch`, which checks whether the entire string matches the pattern.

Comment: There is no way this answer solved the O.P.'s problem since the pattern does not include whitespace. The `re.fullmatch` function simply anchors the pattern at both ends of the string being matched.

Comment: @KurtisRader The OP wanted the pattern *not* to match their example string, but it *did* match, precisely because it was not anchored at the ends.